# I can't fix the gap between body and footer

Tags: css, footer

There seems to be a gap between the footer and main body. i want the body to touch the footer, as seen i want it to completely fill up the space in the middle.

https://ibb.co/dUpFJF

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.div_top1 {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

.div_top2 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #072135;
}

.main_container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFF;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container_right {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container_left {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 2px solid #5a5c5d;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5a5c5d;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bk {
  border-top: 4px solid #da6161;
  display: table;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.icon {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.icon-bar {
  width: 70px;
  /* Set a specific width */
  background-color: #FFF;
  /* Dark-grey background */
  height: 100%;
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  /* Make the links appear below each other instead of side-by-side */
  text-align: center;
  /* Center-align text */
  padding: 16px;
  /* Add some padding */
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  /* Add transition for hover effects */
  color: black;
  /* White text color */
  font-size: 27px;
  /* Increased font-size */
  height: 100%;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #5a5c5d;
  /* Add a hover color */
}

.active {
  background-color: #818384;
  /* Add an active/current color */
}

<style>
/* Tooltip container */

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}


/* Tooltip text */

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #da6161;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 36px;
}


/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.foot {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  position: absolute;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 3px solid #9c9d9e;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="div_top2"> </div>
  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="container_left">
      <div class="icon_menu">
        <div class="icon-bar">
          <a class="active tooltip" href="#">
            <span class="tooltiptext">Home</span>
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>

          </a>
          <a class="tooltip" href="#">
            <span class="tooltiptext">My Story</span>
            <i class="fa fa-black-tie"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="tooltip">
            <span class="tooltiptext">Companies</span>
            <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="tooltip">
            <span class="tooltiptext">Blog</span>
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
          </a>


          <a href="#" class="tooltip">
            <span class="tooltiptext">Ask Me Anything</span>
            <i class="fa fa-quora"></i>

          </a>


          <a href="#" class="tooltip">
            <span class="tooltiptext">Contact</span>
            <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>

          </a>





        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="container_right">

      <div class="bk"></div>

    </div>



  </div>

  <div class="foot">
    Copyright 2017

  </div>
```

Comment: Post the complete code please. We need enough code to reproduce the problem. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: post all the code

Comment: show us all of ur codes

Answer (score 0):

When using floats you disturb the normal document flow. Change the definition of `.foot` as follows:

```css
@charset "utf-8";

/* CSS Document */

body {
  font-family: 'Droid Sans', sans-serif;
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 0px;
  margin-right: 0px;
  margin-bottom: 0px;
  min-height: 100%;
}

.div_top1 {
  height: 30px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
}

.div_top2 {
  height: 150px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #072135;
}

.main_container {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #FFF;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.container_right {
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.container_left {
  float: left;
  text-align: left;
  border-right: 2px solid #5a5c5d;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #5a5c5d;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.bk {
  border-top: 4px solid #da6161;
  display: table;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  padding: 8px;
}

.icon {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}

.icon-bar {
  width: 70px;
  /* Set a specific width */
  background-color: #FFF;
  /* Dark-grey background */
  height: 100%;
}

.icon-bar a {
  display: block;
  /* Make the links appear below each other instead of side-by-side */
  text-align: center;
  /* Center-align text */
  padding: 16px;
  /* Add some padding */
  transition: all 0.3s ease;
  /* Add transition for hover effects */
  color: black;
  /* White text color */
  font-size: 27px;
  /* Increased font-size */
  height: 100%;
}

.icon-bar a:hover {
  background-color: #5a5c5d;
  /* Add a hover color */
}

.active {
  background-color: #818384;
  /* Add an active/current color */
}

<style>
/* Tooltip container */

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
  /* If you want dots under the hoverable text */
}


/* Tooltip text */

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: auto;
  background-color: #da6161;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  font-size: 20px;
  /* Position the tooltip text - see examples below! */
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  margin-left: 36px;
}


/* Show the tooltip text when you mouse over the tooltip container */

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

.foot {
  background-color: #2d2d2d;
  color: #FFF;
  text-align: center;
  float: left;
  height: 35px;
  width: 100%;
  border-top: 3px solid #9c9d9e;
  padding-top: 3px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<body>
  <div class="div_top2"> </div>
  <div class="main_container">
    <div class="container_left">
      <div class="icon_menu">
        <div class="icon-bar">
          <a class="active tooltip" href="#">
            <span class="tooltiptext">Home</span>
            <i class="fa fa-home"></i>

          </a>
          <a class="tooltip" href="#">
            <span class="tooltiptext">My Story</span>
            <i class="fa fa-black-tie"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="tooltip">
            <span class="tooltiptext">Companies</span>
            <i class="fa fa-building"></i>
          </a>
          <a href="#" class="tooltip">
            <span class="tooltiptext">Blog</span>
            <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i>
          </a>


          <a href="#" class="tooltip">
            <span class="tooltiptext">Ask Me Anything</span>
            <i class="fa fa-quora"></i>

          </a>


          <a href="#" class="tooltip">
            <span class="tooltiptext">Contact</span>
            <i class="fa fa-address-card"></i>

          </a>





        </div>
      </div>


    </div>

    <div class="container_right">

      <div class="bk"></div>

    </div>



  </div>

  <div class="foot">
    Copyright 2017

  </div>
```

Comment: I have included it in the code you provided and it works fine. Maybe it is because of the content you use in the containers. If you can provide we can look at it.

Answer (score 0):

you made the footer element absolutely positioned relative to parent(body tag).

try wrapping your code in a  after  element

html

```
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<!-- your code here -->
</div>
</body>
```

css

```
.wrapper
{
position:relative;
}
```

hope this works...